# UISlider too sensitive when releasing touch

Tags: ios, uikit, uislider

When releasing the touch on a UISlider the value of the slider changes slightly and uncontrollably. It's so sensitive that it even changes when just releasing the finger from the screen. How can I achieve that the user can set a value he wants without problems?

That's how I create my UISlider:

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 40.0)];
slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
slider.maximumValue = 100.0;
[slider addTarget: self action: @selector(sliderChanged:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
[slider setValue: 50.0 animated: NO];
```

Comment: try it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324359/how-can-i-control-uislider-value-changed-events-frequncy   hope it helps u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are registering it for all events. Make it for your event only like

```
[slider addTarget: self action: @selector(sliderChanged:event:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work fine for only getting the right events. But on a lower level the real value of the slider still gets changed on touch end, doesn't it? When I read out the value it might be different than the values that I get sent. Is there a way to make sure that also the value property doesn't change on touch end?

Comment: I played with it a bit more but it still feels over-sensitive. Is there a way to make it less sensitive? When lifting the finger I often cause a touchMoved to be triggered which shoud be avoided. It's nearyl impossible to lift the finger straight upwards. But for the user this changes the value - which he did not intend.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to this instead:

```
[slider addTarget: self action: @selector(sliderChanged:event:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And if all you want is to trigger the target only when the finger is lifted, try setting `continuous` property of the `UISlider` to `NO`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but the other answer was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the continuous property.