# Slider determines gravity

Tags: ios, swift, uidynamicanimator, uigravitybehavior

So far I've created a rectangle that starts from the bottom and moves upward using UiDynamicAnimator. I would like the user to determine the "strength" of the negative gravity. I want the user to determine the value through a slider.

This is my code so far:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var orangeSquare: UIView?
    var animator: UIDynamicAnimator?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        func sliderChanged(sender: AnyObject) {

            var sliderValue = sender.value

        }

                //Create animation
            let dim = CGRectMake(100, 500, 200, 100)
            orangeSquare = UIView(frame: dim)
            orangeSquare?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

                //Add item to the screen
            self.view.addSubview(orangeSquare!)

                //Initialize the animator
            animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)

                //Add gravity
            let gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [orangeSquare!])
            let direction = CGVectorMake(0.0, sliderValue)
            gravity.gravityDirection = direction

                //Collision
            let boundries = UICollisionBehavior(items: [orangeSquare!])
            boundries.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

                //Add animations
            animator?.addBehavior(boundries)
            animator?.addBehavior(gravity)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I get two errors:

"Ambiguous use of ´value´" and
"Use of unresolved identifier ´sliderValue´"

How do I convert ´sliderValue´ into a float with just one decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is missing a few things. sliderValue is an unresolved identifier because you have only declared it within sliderChanged but are referring to it in the main body of viewDidLoad. Also, I think that your use of value is ambiguous because you have declared the parameter to the function as AnyObject, whose value could be any one of a number of things!

Your code was missing a mechanism linking a change in the value of the slider with a change in the gravity behaviour. As such, I've implemented this using an explicit target attached to the slider object. I've also thrown in a label showing the magnitude of the gravitational force. This is quite rough but I think it achieves what you were looking to do.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dynamicAnimator : UIDynamicAnimator!
    var gravityBehaviour : UIGravityBehavior!
    var orangeSquare : UIView!
    var slider : UISlider!
    var sliderLabel : UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Subviews
        self.orangeSquare = {
            let oS : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (self.view.frame.width / 2) - 100, y: 500), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)))
            oS.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
            return oS
        }()

        self.slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 400, height: 50)))
        self.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderValueDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.allTouchEvents)
        self.slider.minimumValue = -5
        self.slider.maximumValue = 5
        self.slider.value = 0

        self.sliderLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 100, y: 100), size: CGSize(width : 50, height: 50)))
        self.sliderLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.sliderLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.sliderLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.sliderLabel.text = String(self.slider.value)

        // Assemble
        self.view.addSubview(self.orangeSquare)
        self.view.addSubview(self.slider)
        self.view.addSubview(self.sliderLabel)

        // Configure dynamic behaviours

        self.dynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
        self.gravityBehaviour = UIGravityBehavior(items: [self.orangeSquare])
        self.gravityBehaviour.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

        // Configure boundaries
        let boundaries : UICollisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self.orangeSquare])
        boundaries.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

        self.dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(self.gravityBehaviour)
        self.dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(boundaries)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func sliderValueDidChange() {
        // When the slider value changes, update the label text and the gravity vector
        self.sliderLabel.text = String((round(self.slider.value) * 10) / 10)
        self.gravityBehaviour.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: CGFloat(-1 * self.slider.value))
    }

}
```

Hope that helps. All best!

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion and explanation! :) I fixed just a couple of things. I've uploaded the new code underneath. I've noticed that the slider is a bit too sensitive (it goes from -10 to -9 to -8 etc.). I would like it to be a little less sensitive (going from -10 to -9.9 to -9.8 etc.). I also faced this difficulty with the previous code. Is there a something similar to "self.slider.sensitivity"? Tried to look it up. Couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Not a problem - I enjoyed building it. It would be great if you could accept my answer, by the way, if you think it solved your problem! As for slider sensitivity, there appears to be a discussion on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147068/uislider-too-sensitive-when-releasing-touch All best

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dynamicAnimator : UIDynamicAnimator!
    var gravityBehaviour : UIGravityBehavior!
    var orangeSquare : UIView!
    var slider : UISlider!
    var sliderLabel : UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Subviews
        self.orangeSquare = {
            let oS : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (self.view.frame.width / 2) - 100, y: 500), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)))
            oS.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            return oS
            }()

        self.slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 100, y: 100), size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 300, height: 150)))
        self.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderValueDidChange), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllTouchEvents)
        self.slider.minimumValue = -10
        self.slider.maximumValue = 10
        self.slider.value = 0

        self.sliderLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 100, y: 200), size: CGSize(width : 50, height: 50)))
        self.sliderLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.sliderLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.sliderLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.sliderLabel.text = String(self.slider.value)

        // Assemble
        self.view.addSubview(self.orangeSquare)
        self.view.addSubview(self.slider)
        self.view.addSubview(self.sliderLabel)

        // Configure dynamic behaviours

        self.dynamicAnimator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
        self.gravityBehaviour = UIGravityBehavior(items: [self.orangeSquare])
        self.gravityBehaviour.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)

        // Configure boundaries
        let boundaries : UICollisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self.orangeSquare])
        boundaries.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

        self.dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(self.gravityBehaviour)
        self.dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(boundaries)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func sliderValueDidChange() {
        // When the slider value changes, update the label text and the gravity vector
        self.sliderLabel.text = String((round(self.slider.value) * 10) / 10)
        self.gravityBehaviour.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: CGFloat(-1 * self.slider.value))
    }

}
```